# Why is NirSoft's BlueScreenView not displaying anything?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

Win 7 64 bit here.

Going to System → Advanced System Settings → Advanced → Startup and Recovery → Settings, I have *Write an event to the system log* checked and *Write debugging information* set to *Kernel memory dump*.

The path of the dump file is the default `c:\windows\memory.dmp` and *Overwrite any existing file* is also checked.

I have a 600MB `memory.dmp` file at the path above.

Nevertheless, when I run Nirsoft's BlueScreenView nothing is displayed, it's as if I had no dump file. I tried initializing BlueScreenView-x64 both as Administrator and just by double clicking. I just had 2 BSOD and nothing shows up. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: BSV defaults to looking for Minidumps, which are stored elsewhere (`c:\widnows\minidumps` usually).  Have you tried changing the folder BSV looks in, to the folder you saved your dump to?

Comment: @flennertz Change the default for Nirsoft http://i.stack.imgur.com/CcrEK.jpg

Comment: By changing this path to just `c:\windows` BSV lists only one event of of BSOD, precisely from the memory.dmp file as the Dump File. I just realized this file wasn't modified since some months ago, so probably the BSOD I got today were not written to disk. Do you have any idea of why could that be? I also find it strange that BlueScreenView would usually show me many events of BSOD and I didn't need to change any settings, now if I change that path I get only one ocurrence of BSOD with little information. Thanks for the help!

Comment: One of the reasons it wasn't written to disk could be because you don't have enough disk space. Do you have enough disk space ? What was the error code ?

Comment: Am I stupid or what... I think I understood now the problem. The "kernel memory dump" is a file that (probably) lists only one ocurrence of the BSOD, the last one (since I checked the overwrite checkbox). It cannot in itself store multiple ocurrences, that is, the _overwrite_ checkbox does not _append_ the file. This 680mb file doesn't show much in BSV (e.g., no information is given for which driver caused the BSOD). I'm reverting to "small memory dump" files, as in http://blog.nirsoft.net/2010/07/27/how-to-configure-windows-to-create-minidump-files-on-bsod/ I'll report back on the next BSOD

Comment: @pun I had a memory code, though I can't remember what exactly, I think it was PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA. I have 80gb free in my main hard drive, the one with the OS installed (plus >100gb in external HDDs)

Comment: bluescrenview is crap, use Windbg: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you for the link! Right now I've got some work to deliver, but afterwards I'll make sure to learn this. I've been wanting some walkthrough in debugging, this seems like an excellent oportunity